# Overflow error with Mod in VBA when value is in the billions or greater

Tags: excel, modulo, vba

I am trying to find the largest prime divisor of a number x. When x is smaller than 1billion my code works but when it is greater than 1billion it gives an overflow error and debugging highlights the line with Mod in it.

```
 Sub Largest_Divisor()
    Dim x As Double
    Dim Q As Integer
    Q = 0
    Dim L() As Double
    x = 999999999#
    Dim i As Double
    For i = 775145 To 3 Step -2
        If x Mod i = 0 Then
            If IsPrime(i) Then
                ReDim Preserve L(Q) As Double
                L(Q) = i
                Q = Q + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox (Application.Max(L))
 End Sub
```

Comment: What does anyone think is causing the Overflow error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vba Run-Time Error 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936595/vba-run-time-error-6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it is when `x` is larger than about 2 billion, `2,147,483,648` to be precise, that you have trouble.

That is because as per the documentation of `mod`, at most a `long` is returned, which ranges in value from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647` as a 32-bit signed value. It is not explicitly stated in the help documentation, but the arguments of `mod` are probably coerced to `long` as well.

Comment: Please add links to documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A good work around can be to use this function:

```
Function Modulus(int1 As Double, int2 As Double) As Double

' This function will return int1 Mod int2. It is useful when |int1| exceeds 
' 2,147,483,647 as the VBA Mod function will then break.
'

Dim myInt As Integer

myInt = Int(int1 / int2)

Modulus = int1 - (myInt * int2)

Return Modulus

End Function
```

Comment: myInt = Int(int1 \ int2)
should be the answer 
Using a backslash (\) instead of a forward slash (/) to divide two numbers in VBA will divide the numbers but will round the quotient and return an integer solution.

Comment: @ZionSaal Except that it will overflow if using a `\`.