# Run-Time Error 6 - How to make Mod handle a double?

Tags: vba, excel

I get always a runtime error in vba:

```
 Sub rsa()

Dim c1 As Long
Dim c2 As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim e As Long

pt = "xa"
n = 187
e = 7

For i = 1 To Len(pt)

    b = Mid$(pt, i, 1)

        If b <> " " Then

             z = Asc(UCase(b))
             'Here is the problem:
             c = z ^ e Mod n
             Text = Text & c

        Else

        Text = Text & " "

        End If

Next i
Cells(20, 4).Value = Text
End Sub
```

I get the runtime error at `c = z ^ e Mod n`.

I tried different datatypes, but without a solution.

Comment: what is the precendence?  also are you sure that z is a numeric value?  what is z shouldn't you do this to z:  Cint(z)

Comment: z is 88 in my example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`A Mod B` is equals to `A - Int(A / B) * B`, so you can try to use `c = z ^ e - Int(z ^ e / n) * n` instead `c = z ^ e Mod n`. It works for me

Comment: The problem was because MOD tries to convert `z ^ e` and `n` to `Long` before operating with them, but `z ^ e` is greater than `Long` max value.

Answer (score 2):

Runtime error 6 is a numeric overflow operation.  One of your variables is not defined big enough or without enough precision.  You need to show more examples etc... for people to give you a better idea.  First thing I would do is print off ALL the numbers BEFORE you execute the formula.

Use the datatype Double and when converting to Double use CDbl()

Comment: Well, I did: z = 88 / e = 7 / n = 187 / c = 0

Comment: the problem I see are some of the variables in the calc were not defined (for example e you just assigned a value).  The default datatypes may be INT... you should make sure all the variables are defined and defined the same.  If they cannot be the same then make sure you cast/convert (e.g. CLng()) them to play nice with each other.

Comment: dude..  your calc blows up Long.. 88 to the power of 7 is bigger than the size of Long.  88 ^ 7 = 40,867,559,636,992.  A singed Long has a range of only: 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Comment: instead of Long defined ALL the vars of type double.