# Mod calculation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, calculation, modulo

why vba shows answer "0" when Google shows "11.05"?

```
Sub test2()
Debug.Print 22.15 Mod 11.1
End Sub
```

Q:  Is it possible to get in VBA result the same as Google provide?

---

UPD2:VBA's Mod operator (not function) differs significantly from Excels MOD function is a few respects. First, it handles negative values differently... second, if you use 1 as the divisor, it will return 0, not the decimal portion of the floating point number... third, it handles floating point number differently (it uses Banker's Rounding to round all floating point number to whole numbers before performing it operation on those numbers whereas Excel doesn't).

Comment: From the documentation: [If either number is a floating-point number, it is first rounded to an integer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/mod-operator)

Comment: @cybernetic-nomad
Thank you a lot.
Is it possible to get result the same as Google provide?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20936774/6706419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Mod` in VBA only deals with integers, you'll have to *scale* your values, for example with `10 ^ 3` (1000) if you have values of *three* decimals or less:

```vb
DecimalCount = 3
Scaling = 10 ^ DecimalCount

Debug.Print (22.15 * Scaling Mod 11.1 * Scaling) / Scaling
 11.05 

Debug.Print (22.15 * Scaling Mod 11.075 * Scaling) / Scaling
 0
```

Just adjust `DecimalCount` to match your expected values.

Comment: Wecome to the 50k club!

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Gustav's answer that doesn't need the scaling: First make an regular division, use the integer part of the result (integer quotient) and subtract the divisor times the (integer) quotient from the dividend.

```
Function ModDouble(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
    Dim y As Double
    y = (a / b)
    ModDouble = a - (b * Int(y))
End Function
```

Testing it:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print ModDouble(5, 3)
    Debug.Print ModDouble(22.15, 11.1)
End Sub

> 2
> 11.05
```

Comment: Looks good, but a=33.3 b=11.1 shows 11,1, not 0

Comment: Yeah, made some test, it's an issue with the Double format that cannot exactly store a value like ' 33.3'. Tried to solve this, but it's all not really clean - the updated version returns a value that is nearly 0, but not exactly, so you would need to implement some kind of rounding, and then there is no benefit compared to the version of Gustav. Thought about deleting this answer but will keep it - as a warning.

Comment: better to keep it as reminder, thank you for help